# What is the use of alt in area of map

Tags: html

What is the use of alt attribute in area element of map.It is said that it is used for alternate text, but how is that alternate text displayed and if displayed where it is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specified a HREF attribute in the area tag.
And for some reason (slow internet connection or erroneous rendering of the page in say mobile devices) the HREF is not loaded / displayed properly.
In such scenarios providing the ALT attribute might give some information about the HREF.

Answer (score 1):

- The alt attribute specifies an alternate text for an area, if the
  image cannot be displayed.
- The alt attribute provides alternative information for an image if a
  user for some reason cannot view it (because of slow connection, an
  error in the src attribute, or if the user uses a screen reader).
- The alt attribute is required if the href attribute is present.